# Improving performance of authorization checks in rails model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am looking at improving the performance of a controller action in our Rails application. After looking at some perf counters I now know that the problem lies with the way we have multiple authorization checks peppered throughout our model code. They look something like:

```
Class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
def member?(user)
  #look up a table to check for membership if @is_member does not exist else return @is_member
end

def employee?(user)
  #look up a table to check for membership
end    

def manager?(user)
  #look up a table to check for membership
end
end 

class SomeModel < ActiveRecord::Base
def some_method
    do_something if current_company.employee?(current_user)
end
end
```

Since there are a bunch of places where we do a check similar to some_method, requests typically end up hitting the database a LOT of times. This seems like a wasteful way of doing things. What are the ways to speed up such authorization checks? (Assuming that caching is the way to go here)

Answer (score 0):

Since authorizations change rarely, and it appears you have a finite list of memberships to account for, you could:

- Add column to the user database for each role
- create a callback on the role model to calculate memberships for the user

That way, you only calculate memberships once, when the role is saved. Everything else is a simple/fast column lookup.

Comment: This method (if i understood it right) will not work in my case because although the list of memberships is finite, it is dynamic ie. A user can be a member of a potentially large number of Companies. The current implementation is still pretty fast single table lookup (from an association table that maps user to company and has a role mask indicating membership level). I'm looking at ways to effectively avoid hitting the db since this membership check is called several times per request and memberships really don't change over time.